# Can a pointer in C be the Ident of a StructureTypeDeclaration?

Tags: c, struct

What would be the tagName and the Ident of the following Declaration?

```
typedef struct element *list;
struct element {int value; list next};
```

Would it be possible to declare it like this:

```
typedef struct element {int value; list next} *list;
```

Comment: Did you try compiling it? What happened?

Comment: A 'link' is not the same as a 'chain'. And, an 'iitem' is not a 'list'. Unmitigated's response below is correct. The data structure being declared is just one node of a linked list. Naming it 'list' is deceptive...

Comment: Unless you are writing for some IOCCC challenge, I'd consider that maybe you don't really want to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The second version does not work because `list` is not defined at that point. You would need to explicitly specify the type as `struct element*`.

```c
typedef struct element {int value; struct element* next;} *list;
```